# Does NodeJS's https module follow redirects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the [NodeJS https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) to fetch pages and process them during testing. I can't find any mention of following redirects either there or in the [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) documentation.

From experience I would assume that an `https.request` does not automatically follow redirects (through `response.headers.Location`), but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: TL;DR It doesn't.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about it: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodejs doesn't follow redirects by default.

The following article explains this http://syskall.com/how-to-follow-http-redirects-in-node-dot-js/

Comment: That's not what I was asking.

Comment: Can you explain then in more detail , what are you looking for? Example:Creating a rest API or application? Or what are you testing?

Comment: A more definite answer to my question. So far, one comment confirms my experience (without a source) and one says the doc doesn't mention it, just like I had stated in the question. Maybe there is no more to be said about the subject, but I don't know, so I asked.

Comment: The answer to your question is the following:Node by default doesn't follow redirects, only with the redirect module can change this behavior.